# android swipe not detected inside a  fragment

Tags: android, swipe, gesture-recognition

I have a project that is based on a tab host and uses fragments,

on one tab it haves a listFragment, user taps a cell and goes to a different fragment,

from there user can swipe between fragments of that tab,

i have the project working until i go to the cell of the listFragment,

there i need to detect the swipes left or right to change the fragments accordingly,

here my code:

```
public class PrepareSkin extends Fragment implements OnGestureListener{

      private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
       private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
       private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

       private GestureDetector gestureScanner;


    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);


      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prepare_skin, container, false);

       Log.i("Mirko", "CREATO <<");


      return myFragmentView;
     }

       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
       {
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
       }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
               if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                   return false;
               // right to left swipe
               if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                   Log.i("Mirko", "LEFTERS <<");


               }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                   Log.i("Mirko", "rIGTHERS >>");

               }
               else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // nothing
           }

                   return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

so why is my gesture recognizer not working?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This link seems up your alley : [Android Fragment onCreateView with Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421368/android-fragment-oncreateview-with-gestures)

Although they do not implement `OnGestureListener` into their class, but rather attach a clickListener to their whole View and then trigger the Gesture Listener that way, it should still apply to your snippet of code.

Another quick fix may be that you return `onDown()` as false - perhaps you should return it as true. I know that Android won't recognize an `onUp()` if `onDown()` doesn't return `true` prior.